# how do I make SharePoint top navigation menus with scroll bar?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, global-navigation

I want to apply scroll bar to top navigation in SharePoint 2013.
I want to make something like
[image]

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Not to be that guy, but is that not a really non-intuitive way of building a top navigation? How are users supposed to now what is hiding and that something is hiding? Better split it on two rows or do some IA work to eliminate some nodes from the topnav

Comment: i have done something like  more functionality at the end of visible line of menu and when am clicking on that it shows rest of the nodes like drop down list style, but the above stated issue  is one of  my requirement and I am not able to reach to it.